# Анкета в Телеграмм-боте

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, бот

Пишу ТГ-бота. Бот задаёт несколько вопросов последовательно и считывает после каждого вопроса ответ пользователя.
Сделал так, что каждый ответ пишется в БД. Так образом у меня есть некоторый буфер с ответами для каждого пользователя.
Подозреваю, что должен быть инструмент или фреймворк, которые могли бы сделать это проще. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужный путь.

Бот работает через вебхуки на node.js.